# Python/numpy points list to black/white image area

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm trying to convert a continuous list points (between 0 and 1) into black and white image, representing area under/over list points.

```
plt.plot(points)
plt.ylabel('True val')
plt.show()
print("Points shape-->", points.shape)
```

[image: result]

I can save the image produced by matplotlib but i think this could be a nasty workaround

At the end i would like to obtain and image with shape of (224,224) where white zone represent area under line and black zone represent are over line...

```
image_area = np.zeros((points.shape[0],points.shape[0],))
# ¿?
```

Any ideas or suggestions how to approach it are welcome! Thanks experts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a basic example of how you could do it. Since the slicing requires integers, you may have to scale your raw data first.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# your 2D image
image_data = np.zeros((224, 224))

# your points. Here I am just using a random list of points
points = np.random.choice(224, size=224)

# loop over each column in the image and set the values
# under "points" equal to 1
for col in range(len(image_data[0])):
    image_data[:points[col], col] = 1

# show the final image
plt.imshow(image_data, cmap='Greys')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Eric, here the solution with your proposal, thank you very much!

```
def to_img(points):
    shape = points.shape[0]
# your 2D image
    image_data = np.zeros((shape, shape))

# your points. Here I am just using a random list of points
# points = np.random.choice(224, size=224)
    def minmax_norm_img(data, xmax, xmin):
        return (data - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)

    points_max = np.max(points)
    points_min = np.min(points)
    points_norm = minmax_norm_img(points,points_max , points_min)

# loop over each column in the image and set the values
# over "points" equal to 1
    for col in range(len(image_data[0])):
        image_data[shape-int(points_norm[col]*shape):, col] = 1

    return image_data
```